# Font "OrbitronMedium" loads but not displays on Firefox 19 Ubuntu

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In my Firefox on Ubuntu 12.10 "OrbitronMedium" font does not apply to menu and other elements. In Chrome Version 25.0.1364.97 on Ubuntu it does display ok.

The same issue on Windows Firefox 23; Chrome 28 displays ok.

`Firefox 19 on Ubuntu`
[image: Firefox 19 on Ubuntu]

`Chrome 25.0.1364.97 on Ubuntu`
[image]

Comment: Nor on Firefox 13 (also Ubuntu) (I've been lazy, shhh).  I actually had no idea there _was_ a special font.

Comment: I just did some digging in the CSS and it looks like [this contains the solution](http://www.unseenrevolution.com/solution-firefox-font-face-cross-domain-problem/) - SciFi's all.css defines the orbitron font just like in that example, and the problem described is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing headers have been found and will be reinstated shortly.

Your FireFox experience should match the Chrome one in the next build (rev 2013.11.1.1108).

---

The CDN is still caching the old headers, so once the cache is invalidated, you should see the fonts loading in FireFox.

Comment: I can seee eeeet....  =o_o=

Comment: Scratch that, I can see it on main, but not on meta.

Comment: And now I see it on meta, too

Comment: It does work. Thank you.